# Rake task firing off mailer not returning correct results

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, actionmailer, rake-task

When an apartment's unit number is more than 10 characters long and the apartment's status is available it should trigger a mailer. The mailer fires off fine, but it returns all listings instead of just the ones I need. Any help is appreciated.

too_long.rake

```
namespace :listings do
  desc 'Notifies an agent when the unit is too long'
  task notify_agent_unit: :environment do
    Listing.all.each do |listing|
      if Listing.where("length(apartment) > 10") && Listing.where(status: 'Available')
        TooLongMailer.unit_too_long(listing, listing.listing_agent).deliver_now
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't get that to work so I added a scope in the model that works perfectly.

```
scope :unit_length_available, -> { where("length(apartment) > 10 AND (status ILIKE '%available%')") }
```